# What academic paper introduces CNNs in deep learning?

Tags: references, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, history

I am trying to find a source for which academic paper introduced CNNs in deep learning.

Comment: I am not sure this question is really "on topic", a better venue might be [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold)). That said, I am no expert and my knowledge is essentially the recent [Nature paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=5362332738201102290) cited below, but from there it seems LeCun introduced them ca. 1990, with inspiration from Fukushima's Neocognitron 1982. CNNs were introduced prior to the terminology "ConvNet" *or* "Deep Learning", so what is the "first" paper? (e.g. *possibly* even on topic for [HSM.SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/)?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network#History provides some overview.

Comment: Asking about neural networks is on topic here, as is asking for references pertaining to on topic subject matter. I don't see any problem with this question.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean introducing in the sense of the first to describe or in the sense of providing a basic introduction?

Answer (score 5):

Two recent papers come to mind:

Lecun, Bengio and Hinton, *Deep Learning,* http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/NatureDeepReview.pdf

Schmidhuber, *Deep Learning in Neural Networks: An Overview,*
http://people.idsia.ch/~juergen/DeepLearning2July2014.pdf

Comment: These are the first paper of Deep Neural Networks, not CNN

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in another answer, the recent [Deep Learning Review in Nature](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=5362332738201102290) has some good discussion of this. I am not in this field, so cannot say how much this is a balanced review vs. just the authors' perspective. However one of the authors, [Yann LeCun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yann_LeCun), seems to be widely acknowledged as essentially the "father of convolutional neural networks" (a.k.a. ConvNets, CNNs). So the Nature review is a reasonable source for this topic, at the very least.

Given this, the reference chosen as the "origin of deep learning in ConvNets" there is essentially this 1990 NIPS paper:

> LeCun et al. (1990) [Handwritten digit recognition with a back-propagation network](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=13003663605837932032). In Advances in neural information processing systems.

The review mentions some earlier work on convolution-type layers, but notes that:

> This is the **first paper** on convolutional networks trained by **backpropagation** for the task of classifying low-resolution images of handwritten digits.

The terms I have bolded lead me to conclude that this paper is a reasonable candidate for the "academic paper that introduced CNNs in deep learning" (i.e. [BackProp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) would seem to be an essential component for the "deep" aspect).

However it is worth noting that in the Nature review the authors mention that the approach was significantly inspired by

> Fukushima (1980) [Neocognitron: A self-organizing neural network model for a mechanism of pattern recognition unaffected by shift in position](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=12437195399081220520). Biological cybernetics.

Finally, as noted in the comments to the OP, Wikipedia has a summary of the [history of ConvNets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network#History).

Comment: I am not sure if there is a preferred abbreviation for Convolutional Neural Network? I myself prefer "ConvNet" over "CNN". So a question about "CNNs" is not about [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNN#Specialized_channels), and "CNN++" would be some improved version of a ConvNet, rather than a successor to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNN%2B)!